# as3 sort associative array by key when theres no object

Tags: sorting, actionscript-3

I have an associative array like this:

```
[name1: [2,4,6], name2: [1,3], abc: [2,5,6]]
```

I know to sort array with sorton when theres an object

```
[{"name": "name1", value: [2,4,6]}....]
```

but how can i sort the other  one...

regards

Comment: I'm going to assume what you've put as you 'associative array' code is just an illustration and not your actual code. You'll have to write a custom sort function.  See the custom sorting section of this page: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html

Comment: Associative arrays (i.e. dynamic generic **Object**s) are not sort-able because they are not ordered in the first place. Even if you **for...in** loop their keys, you'll get them in a random (or rather non-guaranteed, as it might seriously differ between runs) order you cannot rely on.